# What is "Talk with an Expert?"

Tags: support

When I browse this site late at night, I occasionally get a popup that says: "Talk with an Expert?" The options are "Not Now", and "Never".

What is this? Has anyone else gotten it or have I installed a virus (NOTE: it looked native)?

Comment: Haha awesome. I didn't think anyone here would post :D

Answer (score 5):

## April Fools!

[image: Unicorn Clippy]

Comment: Haha - thanks so much, didn't know that SE was into jokes!